# Apex page DML Mail Alert Trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger, functions, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a Trigger and Function which sends mail with "updated" column(s),
when i am updating in my back-end (sql developer), i receive a mail with that particular column.

But when i do UPDATE directly through Apex Page i get mail listing all columns names indicating all are updated.

**Function Code:**

```
create or replace function SNAP_FUN(inTableName in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  result varchar2(4000);
  sep    varchar2(2) := null;
begin
  for c in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = inTableName) loop
    if updating(c.column_name) then
      result := result || sep || c.column_name;
      sep    := ', ';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return result;
end;
```

/

**Trigger**

```
create or replace trigger SNAP_TRIG 
after update on dw.W_SUPPL_SNAPSHOT_CONTROL_G

for each row
DECLARE X VARCHAR2(4000);
begin

begin
    
X:=X||('Updated:' || snap_fun('W_SUPPL_SNAPSHOT_CONTROL_G'));

end;

dlr_send_mail('***.com', 'SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT', 'These are the column changes observed' || X
    , '****', 'host')


end;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like help improving this code so that i could get alert only  for columns being updated. My problem is hopefully understandable.

Comment: Generally speaking, at the SQL level, APEX will always update every column in a form. It does not distinguish between fields that have changed or not changed when constructing the update command.